# Changing Specificity

Tags: css, css-specificity, controlling, css-cascade

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #sidebar p {
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: .9em; }

        #sidebar .intro {
            font-family: Georgia;
            font-size: 1.25em;
            color:red;
            }

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id=”sidebar”>
       <p class=”intro”>
           As you can see, the more CSS styles you create, the greater the potential for formatting
          snafus. For example, you may create a class style specifying a particular
         font and font size, but when you apply the style to a paragraph, nothing happens!
          This kind of problem is usually related to the cascade. Even though you may think
         that directly applying a class to a tag should apply the class’s formatting properties,
          it may not if there’s a style with greater specificity.

        You have a couple of options for dealing with this kind of problem. First, you can
        use !important (as described in the box above) to make sure a property always
        applies. The !important approach is a bit heavy handed, though, since it’s hard to
        predict that you’ll never, ever, want to overrule an !important property someday.
        Read on for two other cascade-tweaking solutions.
    </p>    
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

the **#sidebar p** style has a **specificity of 101** (100 for the ID, and 1 for the tag
selector), while the **.intro style** has a specificity of **10** (10 points for a class selector). Since 101 is greater than 10, #sidebar p takes precedence. Changing .intro to #sidebar .intro changes its specificity to 110.

Even though I have change this my result is not coming

Can anyone explain me.

output: should be in red color, font-size-1.25em and font-family -Georgia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes around the ID `sidebar` and classname `intro` are invalid.
`”sidebar”` should be `"sidebar"`.

The browser interprets the ID as `”sidebar”` and not `sidebar`, therefore, none of your rules even match.

Comment: Just stupid mistak . I took time to realize it. Its working now. The concept I understood but I have made mistake in my coding.                                                                       Thanks

Comment: I am new. So I don't know how to respond with question -answer and other issues. thanks once agai for guiding me But where can I find complete guideline?